# Vue 2. Хлебные крошки в MPA

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Из того, что я находил, так это хлебные крошки можно делать только в связке с VueRouter. Но VueRouter предполагает SPA (либо я плохо понимаю). Отсюда вопрос, как сделать крошки для MPA? С перезагрузкой страниц, как обычно.

Comment: ЧТо значит MPA в данном контексте? Перегазгрузка страниц как обычно — меняете `router-link` на `a`, и вот Вам уже обычная перезагрузка страниц... Если у Вас страница приходит с сервера, а потом встраивается кусками Vue — это вообще не задача Vue, а сервера...

Comment: Да, сделал в `a`, а причём тут откуда приходит страница? Вы имеете ввиду, что вложенность страниц пускай шлёт серер? Типа `Категория - Подкатегория - Страница`